# IFrame Position

Tags: html, css, iframe, padding

I have a iFrame that I cannot get flush on the left side of the web browser. It appears to be stuck. It seems to be off around 300 - 400 px. Any Ideas? Thank you.

Here my CSS code below:-:

```css
 .wrapper {
                    display: block;
                    position:fixed;
                    top: 0;
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 100%;
                    box-sizing: border-box;
                    padding: 100px 0 20px;
                }
                .wrapper iframe {
                    height: 100%;
                    width: 100%;
                }
```

```html
      <div class="wrapper">
           <iframe src="My Source"></iframe>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by making a simple modification to the CSS.

I added `left: 0;` to the CSS.

Here is what it looks like now:

```
 .wrapper {
                    display: block;
                    position:fixed;
                    top: 0;
                    left: 0;
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 100%;
                    box-sizing: border-box;
                    padding: 100px 0 20px;
                }
                .wrapper iframe {
                    height: 100%;
                    width: 100%;
                }
```

Thank you to all who assisted and viewed.

I also suggest checking out Peter's reply, as the information that he provided is very beneficial and informative.

-Z

Answer (score 0):

In this case it is the margin of the body tag, just include this in your css:

```
html, body {margin: 0px;}
```

demo: https://jsfiddle.net/1ap4fg30/

You need to take into account the default styles of the browser engine.
To make all elements render consistently across browsers you need to use some type of css reset or normalising style sheet.

Take a look at this for example: https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Comment: Hi Peter, thank you for the link to the website and the information. I tried that on my website, unfortunately it modified the page, but not the iFrame. It is in a Drupal CMS. I tried to modify the code but I am still working on it.